# Confusion about how to open an existing android app

Tags: android, file

I have been looking all over the place for over an hour for explanation on how to open an existing project and followed the step but it just doesn't work!

If I do File -> Import -> Android -> Existing android code into work space, I get a window that allows me to browse for my project but then when i select the folder and click ok I just can't do anything else...It says cannot import BeginerApp because the project is in use...but there's nothing open!?! Am I supposed to select the file containing everything of my project as the root directory?

Honestly I don't understand anything of what is going on and I'm completely new to android programming. I was trying to do the first training tutorial on the android developement website and I closed the app, now i want to open it so i can test it on my phone... sigh, It's a rough start into the world of Android programming.

Comment: Did you copy/paste your project into the same folder and after to Eclipse in the past? If I understand you right u Import -> Existing Project into workspace -> Select root dir..., right?

Comment: I originally created the folder from the "create new android project" window, there was no copy pasting going no.and ye3s you understand me right =)

Answer (score 1):

Well, If I understand you right in the past you imported the same project with the "same" `.Project` file.

To make to import the duplicated of old project you imported in, go to you new Project and edit `.Project` file:

```
<projectDescription>
<name>PutHereYourNewName</name>
....
```

Eclipse before import checks this file for `projectDescription name` and even if you changed Project folder, Eclipse feels it like you try to import the same project till you change above mentioned file.

After, it should work

Answer (score 0):

Check if a project folder exists on disk in the workspace folder already. in this case, the project files are not visible in the eclipse window, but they are not allowed to be copied in workspace because it is still there on disk.

If you still face problems, in the worse case  create a new workspace, and then import your project.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I just found an option under project that said clean... and I cleaned everything, now I don't get the message saying that the project is in use but all options except cancel are still grayed out and impossible to select...So you're saying I should just creat a new workspace...what is a workspace anyways =/ is it just something that appears when i creat a new project ? Im still at the mental state where everything is magic so bare with me sorry.

Comment: it is basically the folder where your projects are kept. Go to File->Switch Workspace, and give a different folder name(new folder preferably for new workspace) and you get a new workspace. The first time you open Eclipse, you are asked to select a default workspace. If you go to that location, you can see all your project files

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. But I'm still not able to get my existing app to work -_- . Any ways, I created a new one and I finaly got it to work on my phone. Yay! my first android app.